# remove "opacity" in stripe form

Tags: css, stripe-payments

on my website I'm using stripe to process payments, in particular, I'm using the auto-generated form using [stripe elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

The problem is that in the stripe form it seems like there is an opacity that I can't remove:

[image]

As you can see the placeholder in the stripe form is lighter in some way.
I style them in the same way:

```
  const baseStyle = {
      base: {
          color: "#000",
          lineHeight: "40px",
          fontFamily: "Lato, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: "300",
          fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
          fontSize: "14px",
          "::placeholder": {
              color: "#757575",
          },
      },
  },
```

Then I mount the form:

```
this.card = this.stripe.elements().create("card", { style: baseStyle });
```

There is no particular style for my placeholder, I just have the general text color set to #757575. There's no opacity involved.

When I fill the input with some text I have the same problem: on the stripe form it looks "lighter".

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

This is the inspector, even here I don't see nothing that could cause that "opacity":

[image]

EDIT 2:

This is the color style after the  tag:

```
.ElementsApp, .ElementsApp .InputElement {
  line-height: 40px;font-family: Lato, sans-serif;font-weight: 300;font-size: 14px;height: 40px;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement + .Input-placeholder--ie {
  opacity: 1;color: #757575;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #757575;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #757575;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #757575;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #757575;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement.is-invalid {
  color: #fa755a;
}
.ElementsApp:not(.is-autofilled) .InputElement.is-invalid:-webkit-autofill {
  color: #fa755a;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fa755a;
}
.ElementsApp.is-invalid .Icon-fill--invalid {
  fill: #fa755a;
}
```

Even here, nothing relevant...

Comment: Can you inspect the generated HTML and see what styles are applied?

Comment: Gotta ask, have you tried adding !important?

Comment: In the `html`, just after `form` begins, there is a `<style>` tag which I think contains `color` rules. You can target these with your own CSS and use `!important` to overrule. You are not seeing low `opacity`, but color `#aab7c4`... I think

Comment: Check the computed style (in the "Computed" tab of your inspector). From there you can probably see if the color or opacity is being manipulated.

Comment: you need to also inspect the inner-editor div & the input it's self

Comment: @ste You won't be able to target the styles as @ovokuro suggests because the elements are inside an iframe. Can you reproduce this in an [interactive snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or on jsFiddle? The way you specify `::placeholder` should be working.